# while loops, how to set things equal and break while loop?

Tags: python

I am in Ap computer science( i will never touch CS after this ugghhh) and have to do this python problem using While loops. The problem is:
"As a future athlete you just started your practice for an upcoming event. On the first day you run *x* miles, and by the day of the event you must be able to run *y* miles.

Calculate the number of days required for you to finally reach the required distance for the event, if you increases your distance each day by 10% from the previous day.

Print one integer representing the number of days to reach the required distance"
and so far i've come up with this:

```
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    days=1
    while x<y:
     x=x*0.1 
     days= days+1
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. It's much easier for us to test your code if we can simply copy-paste rather than transcribing from an image

Comment: Multiplying `x` by `0.1` decreases it, not increases it

Comment: i'm sorry, im new to this site. I will delete the picture and put in copy paste

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
All you've done is to drop some homework code here -- no problem specified, no question.  You made a math error that's simple to trace: put in `print(x)` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should increment your day then print it out your while loop, also only multiplying by 0.1 is like dividing by 10 so you should not forget to add your x value, try like this:

```py
x = int(input("On the first day you run: \n"))
y = int(input("and by the day of the event you must be able to run:\n"))
day = 1
while x<y:
    x += x+x*0.1
    day += 1
print(f'you should run {day} days')
```